# Google Apis are accessible to Cloud function even after all the egress traffic is routed to Serverless VPC Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-vpc

[image: GCP documentation]

According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20your%20function%20is%20unable%20to%20access%20the%20public%20internet%20unless%20you%20configure%20Cloud%20NAT.%20Further%20note%20that%20you%20need%20your%20Cloud%20NAT%20to%20map%20all%20primary%20and%20secondary%20IP%20ranges%20for%20all%20subnets%20to%20the%20NAT%20gateway%2C%20in%20order%20to%20include%20the%20connector%27s%20subnet%20in%20the%20mapping.) in GCP if a cloud function is connected to a VPC through Serverless VPC accessor and all the egress traffic from the function is routed to Serverless VPC accessor, the **cloud function should not have access to internet**. This is working fine for other APIs but Google APIs are still accessible.

I was connecting BigQuery from Cloud Function(Nodejs) privately using Serverless VPC accessor. So I expect the function to fail when I route all the egress traffic from the function to the Serverless VPC accessor because I haven't added the Cloud NAT. If I try to access any API other than google APIs (using node-fetch) it is failing as expected.

*Please note: Default internet gateway is present in the VPC subnet*

**Cloud function codes:**

1. Cloud function accessing BigQuery - **It is expected to fail but working**

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

exports.getCountries = async (req, res) => {

  const query = "SELECT DISTINCT country_name FROM `bigquery-358204.covid_19_data.covid19_open_data` ORDER BY country_name;";

  const options = {
    query: query,
    location: 'US',
  };

  // Run the query as a job
  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

  // Wait for the query to finish
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();

  let message = JSON.stringify(rows);
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

2. Cloud function accessing an API other than google APIs - It is failing as expected

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  let resp = await fetch('https://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0');
  let body = await resp.json()
  res.status(200).send(body)
};
```

Comment: Do you have **Private Google Access** enabled? That feature enables access to Google APIs and is enabled on a per-subnet basis.

Comment: @JohnHanley - It was off

Comment: This scenario was reproduced and the only way to reach Google APIs is enabling Private Google Access. If you’re sure it is configured as it is supposed to be done, and still you have this issue, you can open an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) or ask [Google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) where the team can inspect your project directly.